# LinkedList erased in Action Handelers methods in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on an App that simulates an online shop for my Data Structures course, I am currently using JavaFX in the Eclipse IDE and Scene Builder for the GUI design, however I am trying to use a Double LinkedList to store the Accounts in the Sign In UI window, but for some reason every time that I try to insert a new Account object (in the Action Event method) into my List it doesn't inserts it, at least if I try to print it´s toString gives me a Null pointer Exception, but if the insert and the println is in the start method works. Last year a did an MP3 player using JavaFX but in Netbeans and I didn't use Scene Builder and the List did work, some one has any idea why is this happening?

```
package com.javafx.quvbi.controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
public class interfazController extends Application {

   @FXML
   private Button pausa, CreateAccBttn, LoginBttn;
   @FXML
   private TextField NameTF, AccountTF, PasswordTF, CardTF;

   //Data
   ListaDobleEnlazada<Account> accList;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      //NameTF = new TextField();
      //AccountTF = new TextField();
      //PasswordTF= new TextField();
      //CardTF = new TextField();
      accList = new ListaDobleEnlazada<Account>();
      //accList.insertarInicio(new Account("Diego","Qubi","22f24rf2",123321));

      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/OptionUI.fxml"));
      Scene scene = new Scene(root);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();


      System.out.println(accList.toString());
   }

   public ListaDobleEnlazada<Account> getAccounts() {
      return accList;
   }

   @FXML
   public void controlMusica(ActionEvent event) {
      System.out.println("musica");
      System.out.println(getAccounts().getInicio().toString());

   }



   public void CreateAccClick(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {

      if(!NameTF.getText().isEmpty() && !AccountTF.getText().isEmpty() && !PasswordTF.getText().isEmpty() && !CardTF.getText().isEmpty()) {

         accList.insertarInicio(new Account(NameTF.getText(), AccountTF.getText(), PasswordTF.getText(), Integer.parseInt(CardTF.getText())));

      }




   }
   @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
   public void createAccount(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
      if(!NameTF.getText().isEmpty() && !AccountTF.getText().isEmpty() && !PasswordTF.getText().isEmpty() && !CardTF.getText().isEmpty()) {
         Parent loginUI = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/GUI2.fxml"));
         Scene logInScene = new Scene(loginUI);
         Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
         window.setScene(logInScene);
         window.show();
         System.out.println(NameTF.getText());
         System.out.println(AccountTF.getText());

         System.out.println(PasswordTF.getText());

         System.out.println(CardTF.getText());

         //this.accList.insertarInicio(new Account(NameTF.getText(), AccountTF.getText(), PasswordTF.getText(), Integer.parseInt(CardTF.getText())));

      }
   }

   public void loginAccount(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

      Parent loginUI = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/GUI2.fxml"));
      Scene logInScene = new Scene(loginUI);
      Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

      window.setScene(logInScene);
      window.show();

   }

}
```

Comment: Only post the code that inserts new Account rest is unnecessary.

Comment: You have your `Application` subclass also functioning as your FXML controller class. This results in two instances of your class being created, the one created by the JavaFX runtime during the launch process and the one created by the `FXMLLoader` during the load process. The former instance is the one that has `#start(Stage)` invoked, meaning your list never initialized for the latter instance. This is one of the reasons why you should never have your `Application` subclass and FXML controller class be the same class. Separate the two.